# Why there is an error line on word "storage", delete files on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

As guided in this, [Delete Files on Android...](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/delete-files) Why there is an error on word "storage"?

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

StorageReference desertRef = storageRef.child("Tuition Image");

desertRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted successfully
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you implemented this on top:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
```

Comment: Its work! I thought only declare for FirebaseReference,,

Comment: But the image in the storage did not deleted, can you help me?